# "You as the parent is aware" versus "you as the parent are aware"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Which sentence is correct?

> You as the parent are aware of this letter.

> You as the parent is aware of this letter.

Should I use the first sentence because of *you*, although *parent* is a singular word? In that case isn't *you as the parent* used as collective form?

Comment: A parent is aware of the letter but You (as a parent) are aware of ...

Comment: The basic sentence is 'You are aware of this letter'. 'As a parent' is just a phrase describing 'you' - it doesn't affect the verb.

Comment: Keep in mind that "you" can be singular or plural, depending on context (in your example "the parent").

Answer (score 4):

Kate Bunting's comment about using *are* in that sentence is correct. The subject is *you*; therefore, the verb should be *are*.

It's also worth noting that most English speakers would write *As the parent, you are aware of this letter.*
This is likely to be less confusing (and it makes clear why the verb should be *are* instead of *is*).

Comment: Please include what Kate Bunting's answer was. Currently, this is not a standalone answer and the comment you're referring to could easily be deleted.

Comment: 'It's also worth noting that most English speakers would tidy up this sentence by writing "As the parent, you are aware of this letter."' I don't know, the phrasing in the original question sounds a lot more official to me - the sort of thing you might see on an official document being sent out by the government.